# The LaTeX raw texts appear in wikipedia in my Chrome browser. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know why this happens? I didn't have any problems until now, then this happens suddenly. My computer is MacBook Pro with Mojave version 10.14.6. I googled a lot, but it seems like no one has ever asked this question before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Troubleshooting and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Browser_notes ? You can write to administrators if you believe you need it

Comment: @MattAllegro This resolved my problem! Thanks a lot!